# How can I define a function for calculating accuracy, precision, recall and f1

Tags: python, function, classification

I would like to calculate accuracy, precision, recall and f1 for linear regression, random forest and bernoulli. I came up with the following code:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print (accuracy)
precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')
print (precision)
recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')
print(recall)
f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')
print(f1)
```

How can I define it as function, so I don't have to write the code three times but am rather just able to apply the function.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```py
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

def print_scores(score_functions, test, pred):
    for score_function in score_functions:
        print(score_function(test, pred, average='macro'))

print_scores([accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score], y_test, y_pred)
```